# DRF Object level permissions check for single field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

How do you add permissions to a model so that any user can add a new instance, but only a logged in user can add a particular attribute?

Django `models.py`:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    recipes = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, related_name='ingredients', blank=True)
```

DRF `views.py`:

```
class IngredientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsUserForRecipeOrBasicAddReadOnly,)
```

DRF `permissions.py`:

```
class IsUserForRecipeOrBasicAddReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow logged in users to add an ingredient AND associate its recipe(s).
    """
    message = 'You must be logged in to add an Ingredient to a Recipe.'

    # using this method so I can access the model obj itself
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Check if we are creating, and if the recipes are included, and if they are not a user.  If so, return False
        if request.method == 'POST' and obj.recipes.all().count() > 0 and request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I see the appropriate calls/prints to the custom permission class, but I can still make a POST request with a list of recipe `id`'s and it does not error with the message.

Notes -

- I am getting two POST requests, both with the same information/print statements, and then a third to the GET (once it is added, it shows the newly created instance - which is correct behavior, but I don't know why two POSTs are going through)

Answer (score 3):

I think a better approach would be to use 2 different serializer(one of them hase Recipes as a writable field and the other does not), then override `get_serializer_class`:

```
class yourMOdelviewset():
    ...
    ...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return SerializerThatHasRecipesAsAWriteableField
            else:
                return SerializerThatHasNot
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

p.s. Drf uses object level permission for retrieving or updating (basically there should be an object already), since in `create` there is no object yet, drf never checks the object level permission.

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @changak is a good one.  Including this as a more direct solution to the question posed.  In DRF, `has_object_permission` is explicitly for an object *already in the database*, but you can use `has_permission`.  From [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), this excerpt explains why you don't see `has_object_permission` being called:

> **Note:** The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be
>   called if the view-level has_permission checks have already passed.

In `has_permission`, you still have access to the data, and can add a check.  Assuming your `IngredientSerializer` has a `recipes` field, you can check with something like this:

```
class IsUserForRecipeOrBasicAddReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow logged in users to add an ingredient AND associate its recipe(s).
    """
    message = 'You must be logged in to add an Ingredient to a Recipe.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action != 'create':
            # Handle everything but create at the object level.
            return True

        if not request.data.get('recipes'):
            return True

        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Comment: any reason you can guess that the custom message isn't populating?  I am getting `{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}`   This appears that the has_permission message isn't getting overwritten.  Thanks for your help in advance, as I am honestly copying/pasting, I'm reading the docs and code as well, trying to understand typical approaches.

Comment: Sorry, I was only answering about the permissions class.  I don't know anything about your routing, authentication, or test set up, so I didn't respond to the note about getting two "POST" requests... debugging the request/response is probably a different issue

Comment: what kind of auth are you using?

Comment: ` 'django.contrib.auth',`   This is just a test case application, as I'm trying to learn.  So any setup is just the basic situation from the tutorial, just slightly different schema to see what DRF is good/best at.